# How to better acquire class data in button click handler

Tags: c#, xaml

My question is if working solution can be redone in more elegant and more efficient way. 
I dont think about remaking whole thing in MVVM pattern, I rather think about better method of passing info from to click handler than striping button of it's content.

The purpose is to have 2 separate empolyee list - left list is a full list of employees and right one is list of employess assigned to certain task.

MainPage.XAML

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LeftGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="200" Height="200" Click="LeftListButtonClick" Background="Aqua">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Width="60" Height="60"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>

        <GridView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="RightGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="200" Height="200" Click="RightListButtonClick" Background="Aqua">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Width="60" Height="60"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Classes

```
class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Lastname { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
}

class PersonList : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _leftList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> LeftList
    {
        get { return _leftList; }
        set { _leftList = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _rightList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> RightList
    {
        get { return _rightList; }
        set { _rightList = value; }
    }    
}
```

And finally MainPage.XAML.CS

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    PersonList newList = new PersonList();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.FirstName = "John";
        p1.Lastname = "Doe";
        newList.LeftList.Add(p1);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.FirstName = "Jane";
        p2.Lastname = "Doe";
        newList.LeftList.Add(p2);

        LeftGridView.ItemsSource = newList.LeftList;
    }

    private void LeftListButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button var = sender as Button;
        StackPanel var2 = var.Content as StackPanel;

        var var3 =  var2.Children.ToArray();
        Person p1 = new Person();
        TextBlock tb1 = var3[1] as TextBlock;
        p1.FirstName = tb1.Text;

        TextBlock tb2 = var3[2] as TextBlock;
        p1.Lastname = tb2.Text;
        newList.RightList.Add(p1);
        RightGridView.ItemsSource = newList.RightList;
    }

    private void RightListButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF. You are doing it wrong if you are using events.

Comment: It's windows store app.

Comment: Replace your "click event handler" with an ICommand (try DelegateCommand), and on the XAML bind the button to the ICommand and the current Item as the arguement of the command.

Comment: WinRT. You are doing it wrong if you are using events.

Answer (score 0):

```
ICommand _addToRightCommand = new DelegateCommand<Person>(person => this.RightList.Add(person))
```

This won't compile for various reasons, but it should give you an idea what to do.

Comment: Not in the base framework. But almost every MVVM framework out there implements a form of the DelegateCommand, take a look at PRISM for instance.